# android : set custom layout for actionbar overflow menu

Tags: android, android-actionbar

In my application need to set a custom layout for the actionbar overflow menu as shown in the image, need suggestions how to [achieve this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJgi2.png).

Comment: edit the menu.xml according to your need

Comment: Can you please provide an example ?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your menu.xml according to your need. Below is just an example to show it is done

```
<item android:id="@+id/menu_save"
      android:icon="@drawable/icon_save"
      android:title="Save" />

<item android:id="@+id/menu_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/icon_search"
      android:title="Search" />

<item android:id="@+id/menu_share"
      android:icon="@drawable/icon_share"
      android:title="Share" />

<item android:id="@+id/menu_delete"
      android:icon="@drawable/icon_delete"
      android:title="Delete" />  

<item android:id="@+id/menu_preferences"
      android:icon="@drawable/icon_preferences"
      android:title="Preferences" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit the following code in your menu.xml file

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/help"
        android:title="Help"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:orderInCategory="100"/>

<item
        android:id="@+id/Chng_pswd"
        android:title="Change Password"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:orderInCategory="200"/>

<item
        android:id="@+id/logout"
        android:title="LogOut"
        app:showAsAction="never"
        android:orderInCategory="300"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your `menu.xml` items you want to display in your `actionBar` overflow menu:

`app:showAsAction="never"`

Answer (score 0):

@Emzor 
How to set custom layout for the menu , I have given app:showAsAction="never" for the menu items , It is displayed as in [image]

How to set custom layout for the menu ? I have to show options as in the Image which is present in my question.